# What type of list is this, and how can I tell?

Tags: 2010, list

I am trying to reverse-engineer this list.

1. What type of list is this?
2. How can I tell/how do I reverse-engineer these in the future?
3. How do I re-create this list?

---

[image]

Comment: This screen looks of a Custom List. In the ribbon List Settings button is grayed out means you do not have permissions. Also you need to post some comprehensive description. What you want to done etc something in detail.

Comment: True, I didn't spot that.  Indeed, you need to contact the Sharepoint Administrator or your IT department to ask that they upgrade your permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in the url - common types are **List** or **Document Library** or **Task List**.

If you want to recreate this list, you will need to create the same columns in it.

Are you familiar with **Views**?  This view is using two 'Group By' - it is grouping first by *Status* and then by *Drill Date*.  These are both columns in your list.  To see this for yourself - select Modify View, scroll down until you come to the Group By section.

Modify View (this shows you which columns have been selected for the current view):
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70328/discussion-on-answer-by-tally-what-type-of-list-is-this-and-how-can-i-tell).

Answer (score 1):

Can you go to Site Actions > Site Contents and take a screen shot of the icon / tile that is associated with this list? Usually the graphic associated with the list is a good clue as to what sort of list was used when it was created. For example if you see an icon with a clipboard then we know a task list was used, each icon holds meaning and is associated with the original starting point for each list.

If you want to re-create the list in the future you go to list settings > save list as template. (given you have permissions to do that)

Example icons for different apps / lists 
[image]

Here are some icons from a 2010 site.

[image]

Comment: Indeed using 'save list as template' is a very good idea!

Comment: It's the yellow one.

Comment: ok... well the icon with the vertical bars usually is related to the "custom list". Also I updated my post with the older style icons from SharePoint 2007.